# ERROR code ETIMEOUT when installing @nestjs/mapped-types

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to install @nestjs/mapped-types and I have nodejs version 18.16.0. It is my first time learning nestjas so I am a little confused. When I try to install the @nestjs/mapped-types it takes a while and after I get this error:

PS D:\work\REG\nest-garage-backend> npm i --save @nestjs/mapped-types
npm ERR! code ETIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fmapped-types failed, reason: A "socket" was not created for HTTP request before 300001ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\glady\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-31T12_44_06_008Z-debug-0.log

I tried disactivationg IPv6 but that didn't work it just went on forver without stopping or giving an error.
I also read somewhere that npm config delete proxy would work but it also didn't work.